# How to combine several hover elements in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a novice webdesigner, and I am starting to learn JavaScript for website purposes. In my latest project I encountered a problem. When creating a menu I wanted to highlight specific elements on hover and click.

```
function hoverAndActive(firstElement, secondElement){
$(firstElement, secondElement).hover(function(){
        $(firstElement, secondElement).toggleClass("hoverMenu");
    }).mousedown(function(){
        $(firstElement, secondElement).addClass("activeMenu");
    }).mouseup(function(){
        $(firstElement, secondElement).removeClass("activeMenu");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(firstElement, secondElement).removeClass("activeMenu")
    });
}

hoverAndActive("#home","#hometext");
hoverAndActive("#bio","#biotext");
hoverAndActive("#contact","#contacttext");
```

I want to create the structure for hover and mouseclick for each menuelement. Though I can get it to work by repeating the structure in the function, I don't know how to write the functionality once and only input the id's for each menu item. I want to do this through JS rather than CSS since each pair of ID's is located in very different places in the html.
 
Thanks for taking a look :)

 Asger Kjeldsen

Edit: Added # to the functions. Phrasing

Edit: adding HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#BodyHead"><div id="home" class="button"><img src="img/home.png"></div></a>
        <a href="#Test"><div id="bio" class="button"><img src="img/bio.png"></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div id="contact" class="button"><img src="img/contact.png"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div id="menutext">
        <a href="#BodyHead"><div id="hometext" class="button"><p>HJEM</p></div></a>
        <a href="#Test"><div id="biotext" class="button"><p>BIOGRAFI</p></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div id="contacttext" class="button"><p>KONTAKT</p></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're putting an element's ID into the function, you still need `#` in the selector. ie `hoverAndActive("#home","#hometext");`

Comment: I see your point, but still doesn't work

Comment: could you add your HTML to your question? It'll help locate the issue

Comment: Any issues with using CSS for hover? I.e. `#home:hover {...}` - btw, you can also use CSS for mousedown i.e. `#home:active{...}`  - this will add/remove classes as needed (automatically, by the browser)

Comment: I want several elements located in different places to get highlightet. I found several methods to do this in CSS but only if the elements were siblings.

Comment: @AsgerKjeldsen you are missing a semi-colon on the mouseleave function

Comment: One more question, are you saying your code does not work? or are you saying it works but you want to improve it?

Comment: Good catch, dont know why WebStorm didn't catch it. Didn't solve the problem for me though

Comment: I want both a text field and an icon to be highlighted when the user hovers over either. I couldn't achieve that through css with my knowledge :/

Comment: @ochi I can get it to work if I repeat the $("#id, #idtext").hover ... for each menu element. I want to write this part once so it isn't repeated for every single menuitem. I tried doing this by making a function, but as I understand, my script currently fires the function once on pageload and then it isn't using the hover and mouseleave etc. anymore. I hope I am not too confusing :)

Comment: I rolled back your edit because you need to leave the original code in the question so that the answers make sense. If you want to show your attempt to implement the answer, add it as an update, not replacing the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `$(firstElement, secondElement)` doesn't select both elements. It selects `firstElement` **within** `secondElement`, i.e. it's equivalent to `$(secondElement).find(firstElement)`.

If you want to combine multiple selectors, they need to be in a single selector string, separated by comma.

```
function hoverAndActive(firstElement, secondElement){
    var bothItems = $(firstElement + ',' + secondElement);
    bothItems.hover(function(){
        bothItems.toggleClass("hoverMenu");
    }).mousedown(function(){
        bothItems.addClass("activeMenu");
    }).mouseup(function(){
        bothItems.removeClass("activeMenu");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        bothItems.removeClass("activeMenu")
    });
}
```

Comment: Really nice insight. I changed this and understand your point, but the script still doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z0jzymu/). If you hover over the "images" you can see it highlights the links in red.

Comment: @AsgerKjeldsen You didn't use `bothItems` in the calls to `toggleClass`, `addClass`, and `removeClass`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. I am not used to coding, so this really helped me a bunch. Thank you guys for taking the time to answer :)